# Unable to receive gmail in MS outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

Here's what I see in the log files after enabling diagnostic logging in Outlook 2016:

```
IMAP: 02:55:21 [rx] 0c1x NO [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
IMAP: 02:55:21 [db] ERROR: "Allow less secure applications is disabled for your account.", hr=0x800CCCE6
IMAP: 02:55:21 [db] Connection to 'imap.gmail.com' closed.
```

And here’s a screenshot from relevant part of my google account settings, in their web interface:

[image]

I only have a single google account.

Is there a way to fix IMAP integration? I really dislike their web interface.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** The web interface says “Use your phone to sign in: Off” and “2-Step Verification: Off”

The settings seem to be correct, and I have not changed them for years. Yesterday it stopped working out of the blue.

Outlook’s diagnostic log says it connects OK to the server, here's selected messages:

```
Connecting to 'imap.gmail.com' on port 993.
srv_name = "imap.gmail.com" srv_addr = 74.125.133.109:993
OK Gimap ready for requests
LOGIN command sent
```

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled?  Are you using the proper [settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en&visit_id=636862260072984440-420614048&rd=1).  After you confirm the settings, if you still can’t connect, I suggest contacting Google.

Comment: I would also enable/disable switch the insecure application option

Comment: Have you downloaded the maximum allowed per day by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound The last e-mail downloaded by Outlook was 30 hours ago. The first one in 2004. I hope they don’t have hidden lifetime traffic limits…

Comment: It’s a certain amount of bandwidth per day.  I would create a second Google account, to see if that account works, if it does I would contact Google for assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that Google has changed it's security measures around 3rd party applications connecting to its service.

To resolve this you will need to do the following:

Activate 2-Step Verification if not already activated

> Navigate to https://myaccount.google.com in a browser and sign in using your google account details.
>
> After signing in click "Security" tab on the left, then click 2-Step Verification and follow the instructions to configure.

Once 2-Step Verification is configured this will allow you to configure app password's via the following method:

> Go to your Google Account.
>
> On the left navigation panel, click Security.
>
> On the Signing in to Google panel, click App passwords.
>
> Note: If you can't get to the page, 2-Step Verification is:
>   Not set up for your account or is Set up for security keys only
>
> At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
>
> Click Select device and choose the device you’re using.
>
> Click Generate.
>
> Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
>
> Click Done.

Once you have completed this you should be able to use the app password you have created to log into your gmail account in outlook. (May take 5 minutes or so before outlook accepts the password.)

Answer was found from this source - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail-fr/67kIlDcTSI4/eU4Oia1oBAAJ

Instructions for creating an app password on your google account found here - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?vid=0-40571905225-1518162545847

Please also see guidance from Microsoft here under "Outlook won't accept my password" - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! At some point I even thought google did that on purpose to push users to their crappy web sites filled with ads and tracking.