# Powershell SendMailMessage credential not working

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
$From = Read-Host "Enter your gmail address"
$UserName = Read-Host "Enter your gmail username (address without @gmail.com)"
$UserPass = Read-Host "Enter your Gmail Password (will not be stored)" -AsSecureString
$SecurePassword = $UserPass| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword;
 $To = Read-Host "Who are you sending this to?"
 $Subject = Read-Host "Subject"
 $Body = Read-Host "Message"
 $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
 $SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $Credential
```

It's responding this error (Note this is not an Administrator account if that is important):

```
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was:   
5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at                                                                                    
At C:\Users\Server\SERVER\Appdata\sendemail.ps1:11 char:1                                                                       
+ Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -S ...                                                     
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                         
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

**EDIT:** In my original question there was a typo (I had `$Cedential` instead of `$Credential`). That is now fixed but there is another error which I put in place since a regular typo isn't too useful.

Comment: The error message reclaims a variable `$Cedential` without the letter `r`...

Comment: Cool thanks I'm going to quit my job and change my name.

Comment: Now it is saying that `Credentials are required`. Any ideas as to why my credentials aren't being processed correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use `$Creedential = Get-Credential` and enter the complete gmail address as username? This works for me.

Comment: Have you set an app password in gmail? - Please see my answer in this article (The same process should apply to your issue) - https://superuser.com/questions/1407673/unable-to-receive-gmail-in-ms-outlook/1407827?noredirect=1#comment2123527_1407827

Comment: I'm running this over SSH so get-credential won't work.

Comment: And yes it runs fine when I use get-credential.

Answer (score 0):

$EmailFrom = "notifications@somedomain.com"

$EmailTo = "me@earth.com"

$Subject = "Notification from XYZ"

$Body = "this is a notification from XYZ Notifications.."

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

via
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252335/send-mail-via-gmail-with-powershell-v2s-send-mailmessage